# resetting values in a VHDL register and stop writing further

Tags: vhdl

I have simple register and getting single bit values from 5 state machines (all at one time). These values are stored in a register as **std_logic_vector** and has to be given as an input to another module. Once the output of this register is being processed in another module, the index in the register where there was a change (e,g 0 to 1), the value at that index should reset (e,g 1 to 0) and it should take no further input for that particular index (but there is constant input coming from state machines). Any suggestion, how it should be done?

The register code is:

```
entity fault_reg is

port (
  clk           : in  std_logic;
  rst           : in  std_logic;
  reg_in        : in  std_logic_vector(NUM_PORTS - 1 downto 0);
  reg_out       : out std_logic_vector(NUM_PORTS - 1 downto 0));
end fault_reg;

architecture Behavioral of fault_reg is
begin

reg_impl : process(clk, rst)
begin
    if rst = '1' then
        reg_out <= (others => '0');
    elsif clk'event and clk='1' then
        reg_out <= reg_in;
    end if;
end process reg_impl;

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, but it seems to me you want something like:

- initialise your reg_out to all ones
- then in the clocked process do a `for` loop to iterate over all the input bits and clear the bits which are set in the input

Like this:

```
reg_out <= reg_in;
for i in reg_in'range loop
    if reg_in(i) = '1' then
        masked_bits(i) := '1';
    end if;
    if masked_bits(i) = '1' then
        reg_out(i) <= '0';
    end if;
end loop;
```

Comment: Not in this way. Initially input values should go to output of register like this: `reg_out <= reg_in` and after that it should check at which index of `reg_in` was **1** and it should use always **0** for that index and at the same time it should not accept further values at that index of input (because continuous values will be coming from another module to avoid overwriting).

Comment: OK, in which case you need another intermediate to keep track of which bits are live and which are not...

Comment: Ok, I got your point. I have added a `select` input, which is `1` when the output has `1` and in that case it should write constant `0` instead of **input** value.